# Поддержка библиотеки на уровне системы android

Tags: java, android

Имеется библиотека, `mpandroidchartlibrary-2-0-1`, для отрисовки графиков.

Она работает только на версии android выше 4.4, на 4.4 приложение попросту не запускается.

Есть ли возможность завести на 4.4?

log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.eurotech.samik.daytimer, PID: 1434
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020059
   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:425)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:117)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:419)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6062)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6095)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5277)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5153)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3183)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3627)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1217)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(Vi
```

'12-27 15:47:28.216 544-683/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.eurotech.samik.daytimer/.MainActivity
12-27 15:47:28.536 544-683/system_process I/WindowManager: Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{527ee12c ActivityRecord{527cb378 u0 com.eurotech.samik.daytimer/.MainActivity t6 f}} appWin=Window{5295fa70 u0 com.eurotech.samik.daytimer/com.eurotech.samik.daytimer.MainActivity} drawState=1
12-27 15:47:28.536 544-683/system_process W/WindowManager: Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (480x854) to layer 21015
12-27 15:47:28.540 544-683/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.cyanogenmod.filemanager/.activities.NavigationActivity
12-27 15:47:33.292 544-559/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{527cb378 u0 com.eurotech.samik.daytimer/.MainActivity t6 f}
12-27 15:47:33.652 544-588/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
12-27 15:47:33.824 748-748/com.android.launcher I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-27 15:47:34.408 748-748/com.android.launcher W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-27 15:47:38.352 748-748/com.android.launcher I/Choreographer: Skipped 234 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-27 15:47:38.596 544-588/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
12-27 15:47:48.544 544-559/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{527cb378 u0 com.eurotech.samik.daytimer/.MainActivity t6 f}
'

Comment: Если приложение не запускается, то вероятнее всего появляется какой-то стек-трейс. Какой?

Comment: добавил лог к описанию проблемы

Comment: или проблема в том,что я использую  NavigationView?

Comment: Библиотека тут скорее всего ни при чем.

Comment: Эффект домино .

Comment: В стектрейсе написано, что ваше приложение не нашло отрисовываемый ресурс в меню. Библиотека тут не причем. Можете попробовать привести код и верстку относящиеся к меню чтобы решить проблему(если она ещё актуальна)